# Appoitment Module

Tags: 7

I'm working on a site in which I'd like a simple calendar that people can choose a day, then choose a time-slot to schedule an appointment. Pretty simple. Doesn't have to be robust or very configurable. I haven't had any luck in finding something like this. Does anyone know of one that exists?

Comment: Perhaps the http://drupal.org/project/calendar could be what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calendar module with the signup module worked perfect. Signup module is key.

Answer (score 0):

[Date](http://drupal.org/project/date) module does the job ;)

But if you want more flexible solution can use calendar (as Krister Andersson commented) or [Availability Calendars](http://drupal.org/project/availability_calendars).